# Passing object with wrapped properties don't allow compile on (set)

Tags: swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults, property-wrapper

I followed this guide on creating wrapped properties with user defaults:

https://www.vadimbulavin.com/advanced-guide-to-userdefaults-in-swift/

Now, I have LocalStorage class which will take this "Storage()" class at the end of the tutorial and then access that object's references to get the data from UserDefaults values. For some reason, when I set a string in my code, it no longer builds/compiles. It works for booleans. An example below:

```
// The marker protocol
protocol PropertyListValue {}

extension Data: PropertyListValue {}
extension String: PropertyListValue {}
extension Date: PropertyListValue {}
extension Bool: PropertyListValue {}
extension Int: PropertyListValue {}
extension Double: PropertyListValue {}
extension Float: PropertyListValue {}

// Every element must be a property-list type
extension Array: PropertyListValue where Element: PropertyListValue {}
extension Dictionary: PropertyListValue where Key == String, Value: PropertyListValue {}

struct Key: RawRepresentable {
    let rawValue: String
}

extension Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    init(stringLiteral: String) {
        rawValue = stringLiteral
    }
}

extension Key {
    static let isFirstLaunch: Key = "isFirstLaunch"
    static let username: Key = "username"
}

@propertyWrapper
struct UserDefault<T: PropertyListValue> {
    let key: Key

    var wrappedValue: T? {
        get { UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key.rawValue) as? T }
        set { UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key.rawValue) }
    }
}

struct Storage {
    @UserDefault(key: .isFirstLaunch)
    var isFirstLaunch: Bool

    @UserDefault(key: .username)
    var username: String
}

struct LocalStorage{

    var storage: Storage

    init(storage: Storage){
       self.storage = storage
    }

    func ex(){
         storage.username = "travis" // will not compile... "Abort 6" 
         storage.isFirstLaunch= true // without line above, it will compile
     }

}
```

Comment: It would be better if you can post a code that is fully runnable, what is `Storage`?

Comment: @matt I apologize... it was all in the link provided. I did not want to copy the entire article...

Comment: There is no point saying "it was all in the link". The link is an article. Your code is your code. We need to know what _you_ are doing, not what some article says. You could have drawn the wrong conclusion from an article. The article could be wrong. What matters is your code. On Stack Overflow when you say you have a problem with your code, you need to _show_ the code you're having a problem with. Not a link. Not some other code. Thanks. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this question, Travis, I was having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, two changes:

```
struct Storage {
    @UserDefault(key: .isFirstLaunch)
    var isFirstLaunch: Bool?

    @UserDefault(key: .username)
    var username: String?
}
```

and

```
mutating func ex() {
    storage.username = "travis"
    storage.isFirstLaunch = true
}
```

Comment: This is it. Thanks so much.